# div in whole height of parent TD BUT with scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I've figured out a strange thing with scrollable div.

Firstly, I should notice this thing appear only when I put my DIV in TABLE.

So, I need a table on 100% of page's height which has:

- first row has fixed size
- second row is flexible and fill whole unused height of page.

The second row has the TD which has the div.
The DIV has:

- to have 100% height of parent TD
- to be scrollable for it's too long content.
  It means the page must not have scroll anyway.

This is the current result.

```css
html, body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.page{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    display: block; border:solid #000 1px
}

span{
     padding:4em 0 0 0;
    display:inline-block
}
#boxscroll {
 padding:0;
  height: 90%;
 width: 90%;
 border: 2px solid #00F;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<table width=80% height=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=1>
  <tr>
  <td colspan=3>
    Some pictures are here.
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50" valign="top">
      The complicated left menu is here.
    </td>
    <td valign="top" height=100%>
      <div id="boxscroll">
      <span>777</span>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  sdfgfd
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  ggfdshgf
      <br/> 
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  sdfgfd
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  ggfdshgf
      <br/>
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  sdfgfd
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  ggfdshgf
      <br/>
      <br/>     
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  sdfgfd
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  ggfdshgf
      <br/>
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  sdfgfd
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  ggfdshgf
      <br/>
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  sdfgfd
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  ggfdshgf
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  sdfgfd
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  ggfdshgf
      <br/>
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  sdfgfd
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>   
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  sdfgfd
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  ggfdshgf
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  ggfdshgf
      <br/>
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  sdfgfd
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  ggfdshgf
      <br/>
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  sdfgfd
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  ggfdshgf
      <br/>
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  sdfgfd
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  ggfdshgf
      <br/>   
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  sdfgfd
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  ggfdshgf
      <br/>
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  sdfgfd
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg
      <br/>
      safdgdfg  опа!
      <br/>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      &nbsp
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In webkit browser (at least in one ) it is ok, but!

**in IE and FF it looks like that (look at the pic).**

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4NeTh89Af-2fnR5UnJTZ1g5OTFtRkwyQmtvTkJRRTJVcHhtRHRnSERURVNFVDRBMDloNTg&usp=sharing

Please, help me!

I see similar themes are presented here already.

But those themes only look like similar with mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
#boxscroll {
    border: 2px solid #00f;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and for the parent td:

```
<td valign="top" height="100%" style="overflow: auto; position: relative; width: 100%;">
```

*Edit You can still make your height 90%

[image]

Comment: must admit I even can't describe what happened this the page after this. It's chaos. )))))))))

Comment: No. Do you see a text? Me neither.)

Comment: I can't understand what answer do you mean? I see in js fiddle "old answer" only (as well as in my page). Accordingly I see an another result.

Comment: My answer, on which you commented, "must admit I even can't describe what happened this the page after this. It's chaos. )))))))))" Sorry man, not trying to break anything, just trying to help and using the above code exactly as stated really works on my side and on the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/c93sxsm4/1/.

Comment: it seems I understood. You use webkit browser, there it works as you mentioned. But in IE11 it looks so. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4NeTh89Af-2eWEtOWE1cG9oakU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Seems that with a table layout on non webkit browsers the height applied to the container height and not to the browser window height. If you dont have to use a table layout you can do this.

CSS

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.container{
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 100%;
}

#boxscroll {
    background-color: white;
    padding:0;
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    border: 2px solid #00F;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
      <div id="boxscroll">
        content
      </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c93sxsm4/). Hope that helps.

Comment: yes, without table all is ok, I tried so before this post. But can't refuse from a table. I don't know another way in order to force the div fill a whole height but a height of a high menu.